# Git clone repo without source files

Tags: git, push, commit

I have a git repo on my server. There is a lot of big files there (4GB, 2GB, 1GB). I want to make a clone of this repo but only with selected file(s) without need of downloading all of theme. Also I want to be able after download one file, download other one. Ie:
Repo:

```
first.file - 1GB
second.file - 1GB
third.file - 4GB
```

I want to clone only **first.file**. When it is needed I want to add **second.file**, change both files and commit and push them to repo. Ot just commit and push one file.

Is it possible with git?

Answer (score 1):

With git you cannot pull selected files one after the other.

But there's a nice tool written on top of `git` to handle large files (binary files too) and all the requirements you have mentioned with many more features. `git-annex` https://git-annex.branchable.com/

Comment: is there any posibility to clone empty repository and then pull single file?

Comment: Using `git` ? No, I don't think so.

Comment: If single file committed per commit, then you could pull or fetch single commit using `git fetch` or `git pull`